# Flutter DART LINT Warning "Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file."

Tags: flutter, dart, lint

I use a Flutter and faces the following warning with analysis_options.yaml.

The following warning happens.

> Missing variable type for 'parsed'.
> Try adding an explicit type like 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file.

for "final parsed = ..."

> A value of type 'dynamic' can't be returned from method 'parseEntries'
> because it has a return type of 'List'. Open documentation
> Missing parameter type for 'json'.  Try adding an explicit type like
> 'dynamic', or enable implicit-dynamic in your analysis options file.

for "return parsed..."

```
   // convert from json to class
      List<Settings> parseEntries(String responseBody) {
        final parsed = json.decode(responseBody).cast<Map<String, dynamic>>();
        return parsed
            .map<Settings>((json) => Settings.fromJsonForSaved(json))
            .toList();
      }
```

How can I fix this warning?

flutter doctor

```
C:\src\flutter\bin\flutter.bat doctor --verbose
[√] Flutter (Channel stable, 1.20.4, on Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.18363.1082], locale ja-JP)
    • Flutter version 1.20.4 at C:\src\flutter
    • Framework revision fba99f6cf9 (5 days ago), 2020-09-14 15:32:52 -0700
    • Engine revision d1bc06f032
    • Dart version 2.9.2

[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 30.0.1)
    • Android SDK at C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Android\sdk
    • Platform android-30, build-tools 30.0.1
    • Java binary at: C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio\jre\bin\java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_242-release-1644-b01)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[√] Android Studio (version 4.0)
    • Android Studio at C:\Program Files\Android\Android Studio
    • Flutter plugin version 48.1.2
    • Dart plugin version 193.7547
    • Java version OpenJDK
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using

```
  final dynamic parsed =
```

or depending on the linting, you need

```
final Map<String, dynamic> parsed =
```